# Casting not working (after gcc update?)

Tags: c++, gcc

I can't understand why following code doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    char a = i;
    char b = (char)i;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get any out put when I run it from the terminal (g++ "./test.cpp" -std=c++17 -Wall -O3 -o "./test" && "./test") and when I run it in sublime text 3 I get ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPf3W.png))

I recently have updated my gcc to 8.0.1 and work with ubuntu ([more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o6X7.png)) but I get the problem with the gcc 5 installed beside it too. (however the gcc 5 was reinstalled for some reason). Don't know if it has to do with this...

Somebody knows why this ridiculous simple cast doesn't work?
Thank you on beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean with "It does not work."? What output do you expect, and why? I am quite confident that this code will behave the same on gcc5 and gcc8.

Comment: The cast works just fine. Writing the numeric value `5` to the terminal almost certainly doesn't show anything sensible; if your system uses ASCII (which it probably does), 5 is a non-printing character. Try initializing `i` with the value `'a'`.

Comment: There's really no practical difference between the initializations of `a` or `b`. Both will be initialized with the integer value `5` (which according to e.g. [this ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) indeed is the `ENQ` character).

Comment: Why do you expect `a` in this line to be printable `cout << a << endl;` ?  See ASCII chart: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

Comment: Unclear, because: you are asking why an update broke your program, that never worked in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It works just your console has nothing to output for your eyes, look at the code:

```
int main() {
    int i = 5;
    char a = i;
    char b = (char)i;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;

    char a2 = i+48;
    char b2 = (char)i+48;

    cout << a2 << endl;
    cout << b2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I have troubles changing again from python to c++ ;-)

Comment: @Josja You are welcome. Just your char holds symbol with 5 code and in ascii table it's (enquiry), To make offset for visible numbers you need to add 48. But don't forget that cast from int to char can cause overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the computer to print the 5th character in its table of characters. This is a control character, [specifically ENQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters). Control characters rarely have visible output; they have some other meaning that may or may not be useful anymore (some, like characters #10 and #13, are quite useful).

If you want the character that prints a number 5, you either have to use '5' or you can cast the value `'0'+5` (which in ASCII would be [48+5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)).

Perhaps you don't understand what a cast does. A **cast** does not necessarily **convert** data in the way you might ordinarily think. Some casts do (e.g., `int` to `float`; some don't. The cast you're using simply reinterprets the data as a different type: at the machine level, it's simply the numerical value 5. Casting it to `char` doesn't change the data from that number; it simply means the output system views it as the 5th character in the ASCII table, instead of the integer 5. If you want to convert it to the character `5`, then you usually have to do some work (such as what I indicated above).

Comment: A cast tells the compiler to do a conversion. The details of how that conversion is done depend on what's being converted to what. One possible effect of a cast is to treat the bits of the value as a different type; another possible effect is to create a possibly-different set of bits. And note that the language doesn't "[view] it as the 5th character in the ASCII table"; it views it as the value 5. It's the **output system** that converts numeric values to character glyphs.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks. That was pretty sloppy writing on my part. I've tried to improve it, and would be happy to keep improving it if need be.

Comment: Sorry about this serial correction: for values from 0 to 9 you can get the corresponding character value by adding `'0'`; no need for the magic value 48 (which isn't necessarily the right value for character encodings other than ASCII)

Comment: :-) I originally had `0` but thought that, for pedagogical reasons (based on that table!), it would be better to put 48...